# How to plot specific colors for a range of values in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have a df that looks like below:

```
S.No  Date          A   

0     12/07/03     76
1     12/07/13     1
2     12/07/23     32
3     12/08/03     12
4     12/08/04     22 
5     12/08/05     11
```

I want to have a plot where the Y axis is A and X axis the Date, and the problem is with the color. I want all the occurences of 76 in red, 32 in blue and all other values of A in green color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so:

```
# define the color according to the values of df['A']
colors = np.select((df['A'].eq(76), df['A'].eq(32)), ('r','b'), 'g')

# pass the color to plt.scatter
plt.scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['A'], c=colors)
```

Output:

[image]